# Disabled entries showing up

Tags: entry, structure

On the following screenshot the image on the right called Crown Wood - Plot 1 is disabled in the CMS, so I'd like it not to show up in the results.

Below is my code. I added `.status('live')` to the for loop as suggested elsewhere in the forum but the disabled posts are still showing up.

Can someone help, as I only want the section to show live entries.

[image]

```
{% set var = craft.entries.positionedAfter(entry).level('2') %}
{% for entry in var.limit('5').status('live') %}
<div class="related-carousel-cell">
  <div class="property">
    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
      <div class="wrap">
      {% if entry.plotGallery.first() %}
        <img src="{{ entry.plotGallery.first().getUrl('relatedArticlesLarge') }}" class="property-image img-responsive" alt="{{ entry.title }}">
      {% endif %}
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h2>{{ entry.parent ? entry.parent.title }} - <span style="white-space: nowrap;">{{ entry.title }}</span></h2>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I some sort of Caching at play here?

Comment: I've already tried clearing the cache and have cache killer plugin on the browser active

Answer (score 2):

The code is correct, it was that I hadn't disabled the individual entries in the CMS, I'd only disabled the parent in the structure.

So adding `.status('live')` on the end of the for loop is the solution, and making sure every entry at all levels is disabled.

Comment: `.status('live')` shouldn’t be required as it is the default for the status param anyway.